# Mac + Ruby: Can't access ioctl of Socket? How to fix?

Tags: ruby, sockets, raw-sockets

Good time of day.

Ruby Code:

```
def hw_address(iface)
    sock = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM,0)

    buf = [iface,""].pack('a16h16')
    sock.ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR, buf);

    sock.close

    return buf[18..24].to_etheraddr
end

puts hw_address('lo0')
```

What it do: gets mac-address of interface.

Works on Debian as expected. But on Mac OS X, im getting error: ``ioctl': Operation not supported on socket (Errno::EOPNOTSUPP)`

Is there anyway to fix/pass this error message & get working `ioctl` on Sockets?

Comment: Where are you getting the definition of SIOCGIFHWADDR from? On my Mac this does not seem to be defined even in the system header files - there's a SIOCGLIFADDR in sockio.h which seems to do the same thing (but I don't know how to access that from ruby).

Comment: Thanks, got it from sources of freebsd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=97909

"Following function[s] are not available at Mac OS X:

1) POSIX Timer Library (-librt Real Time)
2) ioctl with command SIOCGIFHWADDR - To get the Mac Address of the network interface."

C'est la vie.

Comment: Thanks for 2 years + 26 days answer :)

Comment: Reviewing this even later, as I recollect, I had the same question, found the answer, and circled back to document it.