# How can I send a  Ethernet packet into  network in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ethernet

I install the packetfu gem, and have saw the example and test (partly) but I still don't understand how can I send a frame into the network. I just see the example manipulate a ethernet frame and write it to a pcap file, that's not what I want.

I would like to just use the Ethernet method and a way to send a Ethernet frame into network. The flowing protocal details I prefer to implement by myself.

Of course if Ruby did get a library or gem for 801.x protocol, I will be too happy to hear your recommandation.

Thanks in advance.

Well, the tag tips inspired me and I Googled about raw-ethernet by Ruby and found this http://blog.mudynamics.com/2007/12/04/ruby-tuntap-interface/ I think it's inspiring !

Answer (score 2):

I've never used packetfu, but I've found Ruby's [socket interface](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_socket_programming.htm) very straightforward and  easy to use.  Best of all, no gems to install or keep updated, since it is a standard library, and all you need to do to use it it to require it.  If what you require is simply reading/injecting ethernet frames, at least on Linux, it is [fairly simple](http://blog.mudynamics.com/2007/12/04/ruby-tuntap-interface/).

Comment: I thought it should be simple and easy to create a ethernet frame and send it. I have read some documentation about the socket in Ruby but I guess using socket I at best just send raw binary data? I haven't see it have a method for setting Destination MAC or Source MAC address

Comment: From [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659375/mac-ruby-cant-access-ioctl-of-socket-how-to-fix) it looks like you can access it via ioctl, but not on every platform. [See also](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-ioctl)